# Passport-Local with Gatsby log out does not completely log out

Tags: passport.js, gatsby

i'm using Passport-local for authentication and Gatsby on front end

Generally, the code works fine. When I click on signout, the server returns a 200 call and I get a response "User sign out successfully". I'm then navigated to the signin page. From there, I am unable to access my Post page which is private route. My signin and post page are client side routes

The issue comes when I click on the home page (which is a static page). From there, when I click on the post link, I'm navigated to the post page which supposedly is inaccessible now that I have signed out. My fetchuser action creator runs and is able to fetch the user detail even though I have already signed out from my app

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

**SERVER**

## signout api

```
router.get("/signout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.send("Sign Out Successfully");
});
```

## me api

```
router.get("/me", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

**CLIENT**

## app

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(fetchUser())
  }, [])

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Alert />
      <Router basepath="/app">
        <Signin path="/signin" />
        <Signup path="/signup" />
        <PrivateRoute path="/post" component={Post} />
        {/* <Default path="/" /> */}
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default App
```

## fetchUser action creator

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/me", {
      withCredentials: true,
    })
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
    })
  }
}
```

## signout action creator

```
  export const signOut = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/signout")
    console.log(res)
    dispatch({
      type: SIGNOUT,
    })
    navigate("/app/signin")
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use cookies to control the user state and avoid that issue?

Comment: I m more familiar with token and playing around with cookies. As my home page is SSR while my login and post pages are rendered client side, I'm not sure if that is the problem

Comment: I think it's optimal to handle the user auth with cookies (plus tokens) or `localStorage`, my workaround will be focused on that. If you decided to take this workaround I can provide an answer.

Comment: Sure. If you have reference codes for that, I appreciate and will take a look. I plan to build one using token as a comparison of the various authentication mechanisms

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct and valid, despite personally thinking that handling it with cookies or `localStorage` could be easily maintained.

Your `<PrivateRoute>` component should handle your logic and perform some actions depending on the user state (logged or not), something like:

```
import React from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
import { isLoggedIn } from "../services/auth"

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== `/app/login`) {
    navigate("/app/login") // or your desireed page
    return null
  }

  return <Component {...rest} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Your `auth` service, should handle your requests, in this case using `localStorage` but it can be replaced for your API requests:

```
export const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined"
export const getUser = () =>
  isBrowser() && window.localStorage.getItem("gatsbyUser")
    ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("gatsbyUser"))
    : {}
const setUser = user =>
  window.localStorage.setItem("gatsbyUser", JSON.stringify(user))
export const handleLogin = ({ username, password }) => {
  if (username === `john` && password === `pass`) {
    return setUser({
      username: `john`,
      name: `Johnny`,
      email: `johnny@example.org`,
    })
  }
  return false
}
export const isLoggedIn = () => {
  const user = getUser()
  return !!user.username
}
export const logout = callback => {
  setUser({})
  callback()
}
```